# Plugin eVis false sorting

Tags: qgis, csv, sorting

I have a csv-file and want to load it in the eVis plugin. The csv-file has a column cid and is sorted ascending.

sorting in csv-file:

[image]

I have pictures of a road and this pictures should be shown in the correct sorting. 
How can I mange this in the plugin?

I tried different ways to import the csv file to QGIS, the plugin spredsheet layers, drag & drop and the delimeted textlayers, but got always the same result.

The first object in eVis but with the cid 1009

[image]

Comment: why are you concerned about the order of your features? QGIS doesn't care